# "default" profile folder in a folder redirection/roaming profiles setup

Tags: windows-server-2008, roaming-profile, folder-redirection, user-profile

Usually, under Windows Server 2008 R2, there is a folder c:\users\default. This folder is a template for new users logging on at the machine. So, if you create the folder c:\users\default\Desktop\Test every new user will have a copy of the folder "Test" on his desktop.

In my environment we are using folder redirection and roaming profiles. Where can I find the default folder now? The c:\users\default folders on the single machines are not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile gets created locally using the default profile of the machine that you're logging on to. It's not until log off that it becomes a roaming profile as such.

C:\Users\Default is still there, and it will still be used when the profile is first created.